# Relationship-first queries

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I'm currently writing a CSS selector engine for server-side JS ([have a look](https://github.com/FB55/CSSselect/)!). To have a solid foundation, I started using the tests of [Qwery](https://github.com/ded/qwery) (an existing selector engine). There, I found [a number of tests](https://github.com/ded/qwery/blob/master/tests/tests.js#L211-230) for "relationship-first queries". Apparently, CSSselect (my project) doesn't show the expected behavior, but I'm not sure what's expected.

I already searched for documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful. My current implementation interprets them as follows:

- `>` is equivalent to `:not(:root)`
- `~` and `+` are equivalent to `:not(:first-child)`
- whitespace at the beginning is ignored

Qwerys interpretation seems to differ, but is there anything official?

Comment: What do you mean by `>` is equivalent to `:not(:root)`? One is a combinator, the other is a pseudo-class.

Comment: `> tag` is equivalent to `tag:not(:root)`

Comment: Also, your engine includes a number of jQuery extensions; `:has()` and `:selected` are also jQuery extensions and not part of CSS.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with this case. I'm also working on supporting the Sizzle tests, and instead of removing most tests, I would like to be as feature-complete as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You might have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ (CSS3).

- `>` ≠ `:not(:root)`. `:root` means document root, so your "equal" would be true for every but one element. Instead, it is the [[direct] child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).
- `~` ≠ `:not(:first-child)` ≠ `+`. Mostly because `~` and `+` are different from each other, and equivalence is transitive. Both are sibling combinators, the one [general](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) and the other for [adjacent](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) ones.
- The whitespace should be ignored, I guess. What else would it represent? The [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) needs two *simple selectors* around it. You also might be interested in [The grammar of Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#w3cselgrammar).

Of course a child combinator implicates that the child is not the document root, and an adjacent combinator implicates that the sibling is not the first child.

Comment: "The descendant combinator needs two *simple selectors* around it." Or rather, two compound selectors. But that's a definition for the future...

Comment: The grammar is what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh, right. To cite the current [section 8.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) correctly: "... *is whitespace that separates two sequences of simple selectors.*"

Answer (score 1):

These "relationship first" selectors are non-standard extensions, so there is nothing "official" defining them. From your description `> foo`, `+ foo` and `~ foo` seem to be equivalent to `* > foo`, `* + foo` and `* ~ foo`, respectively.

Comment: I recently found that the [Selectors API level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#relative-selector) seems to be adopting these extensions, calling them "relative selectors", for use with `find()` and `findAll()`. This is going to get pretty interesting.

Comment: @BoltClock, apparently they mean the same as if `:scope` was prepended, and are only accepted in some contexts (when there is a scope.)